# Como exibir imagem com Angular 2+

Tags: angular

Tenho o código abaixo aonde eu preciso exibir uma imagem vinda do banco de dados, a imagem está chegando aqui como byte como fazer pra exibir essa imagem na tela?

```
  <!-- Listar As Bebidas Alcoólicas -->
  <div class="card-columns" *ngIf="bebidasAlcoolicas != null">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let bebidaAlcoolica of bebidasAlcoolicas">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="incluirCarrinhoBebidaAlcoolica(bebidaAlcoolica)">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="bebidaAlcoolica.imagemBebidaAlcoolica" alt="Card image cap">
      </button>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-primary font-weight-bold">{{bebidaAlcoolica.nomeBebidaAlcoolica}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-danger">{{bebidaAlcoolica.valorBebidaAlcoolica | currency:'BRL':true}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Tentativa 2:

pedido-avulso.create-component.ts

```
    loadImagem(encryptedImage) {
        this.imageData = 'data:image/png;base64,' + encryptedImage;
        this.sanitizedImageData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.imageData);
        console.log(this.sanitizedImageData);
    }
```

pedido-avulso.create-component.html

```
  <!-- Listar As Bebidas Alcoólicas -->
  <div class="card-columns" *ngIf="bebidasAlcoolicas != null">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let bebidaAlcoolica of bebidasAlcoolicas">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="incluirCarrinhoBebidaAlcoolica(bebidaAlcoolica)">
        <img class="card-img-top" [src]='sanitizedImageData' *ngIf="loadImagem(bebidaAlcoolica.imagemBebidaAlcoolica)" alt="Card image cap">
      </button>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-primary font-weight-bold">{{bebidaAlcoolica.nomeBebidaAlcoolica}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-danger">{{bebidaAlcoolica.valorBebidaAlcoolica | currency:'BRL':true}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Qual é a linguagem do seu backend?

Comment: Boa tarde, meu Backend é Java.

Comment: O Angular, para renderizar a imagem, precisa que ela esteja em Base64

Comment: Não é byte[] ele chega como uma string no JSON.

Comment: eu abrir este site: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter coloquei a string e gero a imagem que está salva no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

O Angular não possui nada nativo para renderizar um array de bytes em imagem. Porém ele consegue transformar um array de bytes encriptado em Base64 em uma imagem renderizada utilizando uma diretiva.

Eu peguei o exemplo do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324958/6241184), mas dei uma boa adaptada para seu uso aqui.

O código inteiro vai ser encapsulado na nossa nova diretiva, `ImageBytesDirective`.

```
import {Directive, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS, DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Directive({
  selector: '[image-bytes]',
  providers: [BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS],
  host: {
    '[src]': 'sanitizedImageData'
  }
})
export class ImageBytesDirective implements OnInit {
  imageData: any;
  sanitizedImageData: any;
  @Input('image-bytes') encryptedImage: string;

  constructor(private http: Http,
              private sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.imageData = 'data:image/png;base64,' + encryptedImage;
    this.sanitzedImageData = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageData);

  }
}
```

Para utilizar basta adicionar o `ImageBytesDirective` às diretivas do seu componente e fazer:

```
<img [image-bytes]="bebidaAlcolica.imageBase64" width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: não está achando esses imports: import {BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS, DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser'; tem que instalar alguma coisa?

Comment: À principio precisa do @angular/platform-browser

Comment: Não sei não deu certo fazer essa directiva, tentei mais ou menos adaptar esse código olha como ficou lá em cima, mas não mostra a imagem na tela porém não fica com um x na imagem dizendo que não encontrou.

Comment: Pode ser pq a imagem tá corrompida ou houve alguma coisa na encriptação p base64